# YouTube API reports in custom PHP admin

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to show **average watch time** and **total watch time** for YouTube videos from **my channel** in a custom PHP website admin.

We are managing client videos in our own website admin, and want to display the data above **without** the user being logged into any sort of Google account.

We have sample code working, but it only works if our YouTube Channel account has an active session in the background. ie: I need to be logged into **my youtube** account to pull the reports from my channel into a website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your YouTube data is private data in order for your application to access it you must be authenticated.

With many Google APIs you can set up something called a service account which can be preauthorized to access an account data.   Unfortunately YouTube does not support this.

You will need to be logged to access the data there is no way around that.